# How to register breakpoint on watch expression change event in Intellij Idea?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, expression, breakpoints

Is it possible to do that ? I can't figure that out via Expression Evaluation or Watch expression.

For instance I have this expression being watched `name.equals("whatever")` and the method is called many times, name is its argument... And I'd like to stop the execution when it turns TRUE.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Place a break point as usual, then right-click on it -> Properties. In the opened dialog there is a "Condition" edit box, here you could put your expression.